# SQL string size reduction

Tags: c#, ado.net, odp.net

I don't know the magic keywords to get google to answer this for me so forgive me if this is widely available knowledge.

When writing a query statement in code, the resulting string will either be difficult to read (this example is pretty simple but hopefully you get the point):

```
var sqlString = "Select e.f_name as FirstName, e.l_name as LastName from Employees as e where start_date > '2020-05-01'";
```

Or the query will be easy to read but contain a lot of extra whitespace and longer than necessary aliases:

```
var sqlString = 
    @"Select emp.f_name as FirstName
           , emp.l_name as LastName
      From Employees as emp
      Where start_date > '2020-05-01'";
```

2 questions:

Does ado.net or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess do any kind of string compression automatically to make this a non-issue for very large query expressions?

If the answer to the above is NO, then is there a library that can intelligently strip out whitespace and replace long aliases with short ones without messing up whitespace/text within query strings?

Comment: You can run a profiler on SQL Server to measure yourself the performance of the query with and without whitespace. I'm going to suspect you'll find virtually no difference in execution speed. And if the performance is the same, and it's easier to maintain with newlines, does anything else matter?

Comment: It's tedious but not that hard to write something that minifies SQL (I have some code that gets rid of leading space, trailing space and reduces multiple new-lines to a single one (I like keeping the lines around for debugging).  It's not the most aggressive minification, but it helps.  However, it requires several passes through Regexes (at least my code does).  There's not much benefit unless you are going to cache the minified SQL for re-use (that's where my minifier lives, in a SQL cache for use with Dapper).

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention, this is all part of a tiny system that allows devs to write their SQL statements in SQL files in a `\Dapper` folder in the project.  That way, you get syntax coloring and an easy way to copy/paste into SSMS for testing.  You ask the _manager_ to load query `XYZ` and it checks to see if it's already cached.  If it isn't, it reads file `XYZ.sql` from disk (or from a text resource), minifies it and caches the minified result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does ado.net or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess do any kind of string compression automatically to make this a non-issue for very large query expressions?

Fast networks mostly made this a non-issue decades ago.  For most scenarios it's really not going to matter.

But ODP.NET is one of the few providers that has a client-side [statement cache](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featOraCommand.htm#CIHCAFIG), which even works with connection pooling if you want.  With statement caching a statement is prepared and subsequent invocations don't send the query text over the wire.

And you can always format your SQL queries to be readable, pastable, and minimize whitespace like this:

```
           var sqlString = @"
Select 
  emp.f_name as FirstName
  emp.l_name as LastName
From Employees as emp
Where start_date > :startDate
";
```

Comment: Thanks for the statement caching suggestion.  I think I will go this route.  Just aesthetically, making sql statements line up with the edge of the page (especially when it is part of a multi-indented block) looks extremely ugly to me.  I admit, that is just my opinion ;)

Comment: Yep.  But you’re embedding one programming language in a program written in a different language.  It’s not _supposed_ to be pretty.